# F# better performance when mapping a 2DArray -> arraymodule.mapindexed

Tags: performance, f#

What would be a more performant way to process this 2DArray without 3rd party?

```
#time
let ar = array2D[[5.0; 6.0; 7.0; 8.0]; [1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0]]

[0..5000000]
let a2 = ar |> Array2D.mapi(fun rowi coli value -> (value + 1.6) * double(coli + 6) * double(rowi + 7))
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Comment: @Mark - I gave actual code that can be run, the question is valid. I am not sure how to make this more optimal (functionally) in F# but do know how to in C# -> Yes this IS a bottleneck in my code and I would like to know how to make it perform better.

Comment: On my machine, over 10 runs, original code runs in .513 sec.  Switching to simply **let a2 = ar** done an equivalent number of times, the duration drops to .474 sec.  This suggests that just over 92% of your time is spent simply having F# copy the data structure.  I'll be impressed when I see the answer that drastically improves performance. BTW - making it mutable and simply changing it seemed to slow it down, not sure why.  Good luck.

Comment: Is `ar` this small or is it larger when you are experiencing the performance problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run the above code, it takes about 0ms, so I it *really* depends on the context in which you are calling it. If you just run it in a loop 1M times, then it takes about 600ms on my machine:

```
for i in 0 .. 1000000 do
  let a2 = ar |> Array2D.mapi(fun rowi coli value -> 
    (value + 1.6) * double ((coli + 6) * (rowi + 7)))
  ()
```

Here, most of the time is spent allocating the result array - for each iteration, we need to allocate a new 2D array to store the result. This gives you nice functional properties (the results can be shared because they're not mutated) but it is why it takes longer.

You can use some mutation and avoid this. This depends on the context, and so that's why you probably won't get a useful answer here.

For example, in this artificial 1M loop example, I could just allocate one array to store the results and then write there repeatedly:

```
let res = ar |> Array2D.map id
for i in 0 .. 1000000 do
  for x in 0 .. ar.GetLength(0) - 1 do
    for y in 0 .. ar.GetLength(1) - 1 do
      res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
```

This takes about 100ms, so that gives you an idea about the cost of the allocation. But then, you should not do this change if it can break your program because now you'd be using mutable arrays...

Comment: Thanks Tomas, that is exactly what I was after, I see now that its not the mapping of the structure that is heavy, but it is the creation of the resultant array that is costly.

Comment: FYI; there's also the cost of collection (ie the GC).

Answer (score 3):

I did some measurements of this problem which I thought could be interesting.

I created 8 different test cases and ran over 3 differently sized matrixes; 1000x1000, 100x100 and 10x10.

In addition I ran the tests in x64 as well as x86.

In the end I ended up with 48 test results presented in two graphs. The y-axis is the execution time in milliseconds.

[image: x64 performance run]

[image: x86 performance run]

1. Creating Zero Matrix - the cost of creating a zero matrix
2. Copying Matrix - the cost of copying a matrix with `Array2D.copy`
3. Mapping Matrix with id - the cost of copying a matrix with `Array2D.copy map id`
4. Original Algorithm - the cost of the algorithm posted by OP
5. Tomas Petricek Algorithm - the cost of the algorithm by Tomas
6. Modified Tomas Petricek Algorithm - the cost of the modified algorithm to use Array.zeroCreate
7. Reverse Algorithm - the cost of iterating over the matrix in reverse
8. Flipped x,y Algorithm - the cost of the modified algorithm but flipping x,y iteration order

Some observations

1. Tomas wanted to demonstrate the cost of the copy compared to the computation so in his example the copy was not part of the inner loop. I wanted to include his code so I moved the copy into the inner loop to be able to compare with the others. The modified Tomas algorithm is the same code but uses `Array2D.zeroCreate` to create a fresh matrix. When writing this I realize it would have been better to call both of them modified.
2. On .NET 4.5.2 x64 is doing significantly better in general
3. There are performance benefits of using `Array2D.zeroCreate` and populate the matrix over using `Array2D.copy`
4. For large matrixes the x,y iteration order is extremely important. For small matrixes it doesn't matter. This is because how CPU caches works
5. Iterating reverse order over a the array seems to give a small benefit. The reason is that it's cheaper to check `y >= 0` than `y < xl`.
6. The reverse algorithm has to use tail-recursion as F# `for y = (yl - 1) downto 0` uses `y > variable_that_is_always_minus_1` to check for loop end. With tail-recursion we can force `y >= 0`
7. For smaller sized Matrixes the cost of creating them and the cost of the GC is increasing.

The code used to generate the measurements.

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

let clock =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  sw

let collectionCount () = 
  GC.CollectionCount 0 + GC.CollectionCount 1 + GC.CollectionCount 2

let timeIt (n : string) (outer : int) (a : unit -> 'T) : 'T*int64 =
  printfn "Timing '%s'..." n

  let v = a ()

  let t = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds
  for i in 1..outer do
    a () |> ignore
  let e = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds - t

  printfn "  took %d ms" e

  v, e

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let random  = Random 19740531
  let total   = 100000000
  let outers  = [|100;10000;1000000|]

  use output = new StreamWriter ".\output.tsv"
  "Dimensions\tName\tSum\tCollectionCounts\tMilliseconds" |> output.WriteLine

  for outer in outers do
    let inner = total / outer
    let dim   = inner |> float |> sqrt |> int32
    let ar    = Array2D.init dim dim (fun _ _ -> random.NextDouble ())

    printfn "New test run, matrix dimensions are %dx%d" dim dim 

    let run = sprintf "%d_%d" dim dim

    let perf_zero () : float[,] = 
      let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
      let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
      let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
      res

    let perf_copy () : float[,] = 
      Array2D.copy ar

    let perf_id () : float[,] = 
      ar |> Array2D.map id

    let perf_op () : float[,] = 
      ar |> Array2D.mapi(fun rowi coli value -> (value + 1.6) * double(coli + 6) * double(rowi + 7))

    let perf_tp () : float[,] =
      let res = ar |> Array2D.map id
      for x in 0 .. ar.GetLength(0) - 1 do
        for y in 0 .. ar.GetLength(1) - 1 do
          res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
      res

    let perf_tpm () : float[,] =
      let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
      let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
      let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
      for x in 0 .. xl - 1 do
        for y in 0 .. yl - 1 do
          res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
      res

    let perf_tpmf () : float[,] =
      let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
      let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
      let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
      for y in 0 .. yl - 1 do
        for x in 0 .. xl - 1 do
          res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
      res

    let perf_tr () : float[,] =
      let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
      let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
      let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
      let rec loopy x y =
        if y >= 0 then
          res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
          loopy x (y - 1)
        else
          ()
      and loopx x =
        if x >= 0 then
          loopy x (yl - 1)
          loopx (x - 1)
        else
          ()
      loopx (xl - 1)
      res


    let testCases =
      [|
        "Creating Zero Matrix"              , perf_zero
        "Copying Matrix"                    , perf_copy
        "Mapping Matrix with id"            , perf_id
        "Original Algorithm"                , perf_op
        "Tomas Petricek Algorithm"          , perf_tp 
        "Modified Tomas Petricek Algorithm" , perf_tpm
        "Reverse Algoritm"                  , perf_tr
        "Flipped x,y Algoritm"              , perf_tpmf
      |]

    for name, a in testCases do
      let pcc   = collectionCount ()
      let vs, t = timeIt name outer a
      let sum   = ref 0.
      vs |> Array2D.iter (fun v -> sum := !sum + v)
      let dcc   = collectionCount () - pcc
      sprintf "%s\t%s\t%f\t%d\t%d" run name !sum dcc t |> output.WriteLine

  0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting all of that together, very interesting indeed.  My matrix collections were very small (approx 9 x 4). I am surprised on the large difference of performance for x64 on the smaller matrices.  Good stuff !

Comment: Ok, for small matrixes like 9x4 there are tricks to minimize cost of GC. I am cooking up another set of metrics. If you are interested I could post those as well.

Answer (score 1):

*As OP specified that his problem dealt with smaller Matrixes like 9x4 I did another set of metrics. However since I thought my previous answers held some interesting points on metrics with larger sizes I decided to create a new answer*

I did some measurements of this problem which I thought could be interesting.

I created 9 different test cases and ran over it over a 10x5 matrix. All tests run in Release(obviously)/x64.

The first graph shows the execution time in milliseconds:

[image: Execution time in milliseconds]

The second graph shows the number of GC collections during test run:

[image: GC collection counts during test run]

1. Creating Zero Matrix - the cost of creating a zero matrix
2. Copying Matrix - the cost of copying a matrix with Array2D.copy
3. Mapping Matrix with id - the cost of copying a matrix with Array2D.copy map id
4. Original Algorithm - the cost of the algorithm posted by OP
5. Tomas P Algorithm with Zero Init - the cost of the algorithm by Tomas with `Array2D.zeroInit`
6. Creating Zero Fixed Size Matrix - the cost of creating a zero fixed size matrix
7. Copying Fixed Size Matrix - the cost of creating a zero fixed size matrix
8. Fixed Size Algorithm - the cost of OP:s algorithm adapted to fixed size matrix
9. Fixed Size Updater - the cost of OP:s algorithm using an updater function

The Fixed Size Matrix is a `struct` that uses `unsafe` code to avoid GC allocations. It's written in C# but might be portable to F#. It should not be seen as production worthy code, more like an inspiration for something of your own creation.

Some observations:

1. Copying a Fixed Size matrix is quick
2. The Fixed Size Algorithm doesn't perform as good as one hoped. Potentially because JIT:er have to perform some extra lifting because of `unsafe` code
3. The Fixed Size Updater (which is similar to `Array2D.iteri`) has the best performance
4. As expected Fixed Size Matrixes don't create any GC pressure as it don't rely on GC allocation.

It's hard to judge for me if the Fixed Size Matrix is a viable path for OP but it's an option that might be worth considering.

F# code:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

open Unsafe

let clock =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  sw

let collectionCount () = 
  GC.CollectionCount 0 + GC.CollectionCount 1 + GC.CollectionCount 2

let createTimer (n : string) (a : unit -> 'T) (r : 'T -> 'TResult) : string*(int -> 'TResult*int64*int) =
  n, fun outer ->
    printfn "Timing '%s'..." n

    let v = a () |> r

    GC.Collect ()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete () |> ignore

    let pcc   = collectionCount ()
    let t     = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds

    for i in 1..outer do
      a () |> ignore

    let e     = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds - t
    let dcc   = collectionCount () - pcc

    printfn "  took %d ms, collected %d times, result is %A" e dcc v

    v, e, dcc

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let random  = Random 19740531
  let total   = 300000000

  use output = new StreamWriter ".\output.tsv"
  "Name\tSum\tCollectionCounts\tMilliseconds" |> output.WriteLine

  let cols    = 5
  let rows    = 10  
  let inner   = cols*rows
  let outer   = total / inner
  let ar      = Array2D.init rows cols (fun _ _ -> random.NextDouble ())
  let mtx5x10 = 
    let mutable m = Matrix5x10 ()
    ar |> Array2D.iteri (fun row col v -> (m.[col, row] <- v))
    m

  printfn "New test run, matrix dimensions are %dx%d" cols rows

  let perf_zero () = 
    let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
    let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
    let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
    res

  let perf_copy () = 
    Array2D.copy ar

  let perf_id () = 
    ar |> Array2D.map id

  let perf_op () = 
    ar |> Array2D.mapi(fun rowi coli value -> (value + 1.6) * double(rowi + 6) * double(coli + 7))

  let perf_tpm () =
    let xl = ar.GetLength(0)
    let yl = ar.GetLength(1)
    let res = Array2D.zeroCreate xl yl
    for x in 0 .. xl - 1 do
      for y in 0 .. yl - 1 do
        res.[x, y] <- (ar.[x, y] + 1.6) * double ((x + 6) * (y + 7))
    res

  let perf_fzero () =
    let m = Matrix5x10()
    m

  let perf_fcopy () =
    let m = mtx5x10
    m

  let perf_fs () =
    let mutable m = Matrix5x10 ()

    for row = 0 to Matrix5x10.Rows - 1 do
      for col = 0 to Matrix5x10.Columns - 1 do
        m.[col, row] <- (mtx5x10.[col, row] + 1.6) * double ((row + 6) * (col + 7))

    m

  let perf_fsui = Func<int, int, double, double> (fun col row v -> (v + 1.6) * double ((row + 6) * (col + 7)))

  let perf_fsu () =
    let mutable m = mtx5x10
    m.Update perf_fsui
    m

  let sumArray vs =
    let sum   = ref 0.
    vs |> Array2D.iter (fun v -> sum := !sum + v)
    !sum

  let sumMatrix (mtx : Matrix5x10) =
    let sum   = ref 0.
    mtx.Update (fun _ _ v -> sum := !sum + v; v)
    !sum

  let testCases =
    [|
      createTimer "Creating Zero Matrix"              perf_zero   sumArray
      createTimer "Copying Matrix"                    perf_copy   sumArray
      createTimer "Mapping Matrix with id"            perf_id     sumArray
      createTimer "Original Algorithm"                perf_op     sumArray
      createTimer "Tomas P Algorithm with Zero Init"  perf_tpm    sumArray
      createTimer "Creating Zero Fixed Size Matrix"   perf_fzero  sumMatrix
      createTimer "Copying Fixed Size Matrix"         perf_fcopy  sumMatrix
      createTimer "Fixed Size Algorithm"              perf_fs     sumMatrix
      createTimer "Fixed Size Updater"                perf_fsu    sumMatrix
    |]

  for name, a in testCases do
    let sum, t, dcc = a outer
    sprintf "%s\t%f\t%d\t%d" name sum dcc t |> output.WriteLine

  0
```

C# code (for those that care I generated this with T4):

```
namespace Unsafe
{
  using System;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct Matrix5x10
  {
    double m_c0_r0;
    double m_c1_r0;
    double m_c2_r0;
    double m_c3_r0;
    double m_c4_r0;
    double m_c0_r1;
    double m_c1_r1;
    double m_c2_r1;
    double m_c3_r1;
    double m_c4_r1;
    double m_c0_r2;
    double m_c1_r2;
    double m_c2_r2;
    double m_c3_r2;
    double m_c4_r2;
    double m_c0_r3;
    double m_c1_r3;
    double m_c2_r3;
    double m_c3_r3;
    double m_c4_r3;
    double m_c0_r4;
    double m_c1_r4;
    double m_c2_r4;
    double m_c3_r4;
    double m_c4_r4;
    double m_c0_r5;
    double m_c1_r5;
    double m_c2_r5;
    double m_c3_r5;
    double m_c4_r5;
    double m_c0_r6;
    double m_c1_r6;
    double m_c2_r6;
    double m_c3_r6;
    double m_c4_r6;
    double m_c0_r7;
    double m_c1_r7;
    double m_c2_r7;
    double m_c3_r7;
    double m_c4_r7;
    double m_c0_r8;
    double m_c1_r8;
    double m_c2_r8;
    double m_c3_r8;
    double m_c4_r8;
    double m_c0_r9;
    double m_c1_r9;
    double m_c2_r9;
    double m_c3_r9;
    double m_c4_r9;

    public const int Columns  = 5;
    public const int Rows     = 10;

    unsafe public double this[int x, int y]
    {

      [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
      get
      {
        var i = 5 * y + x;

        if (i < 0 || i >= 50)
        {
          throw new IndexOutOfRangeException ("0 <= x <= 5 && 0 <= y <= 10");
        }

        fixed (double * ms = &m_c0_r0)
        {
          return ms[i];
        }
      }

      [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
      set
      {
        var i = 5 * y + x;

        if (i < 0 || i >= 50)
        {
          throw new IndexOutOfRangeException ("0 <= x <= 5 && 0 <= y <= 10");
        }

        fixed (double * ms = &m_c0_r0)
        {
          ms[i] = value;
        }
      }
    }

    public void Update (Func<int, int, double, double> updater)
    {
      if (updater == null)
      {
        return;
      }
      m_c0_r0 = updater (0, 0, m_c0_r0);
      m_c1_r0 = updater (1, 0, m_c1_r0);
      m_c2_r0 = updater (2, 0, m_c2_r0);
      m_c3_r0 = updater (3, 0, m_c3_r0);
      m_c4_r0 = updater (4, 0, m_c4_r0);
      m_c0_r1 = updater (0, 1, m_c0_r1);
      m_c1_r1 = updater (1, 1, m_c1_r1);
      m_c2_r1 = updater (2, 1, m_c2_r1);
      m_c3_r1 = updater (3, 1, m_c3_r1);
      m_c4_r1 = updater (4, 1, m_c4_r1);
      m_c0_r2 = updater (0, 2, m_c0_r2);
      m_c1_r2 = updater (1, 2, m_c1_r2);
      m_c2_r2 = updater (2, 2, m_c2_r2);
      m_c3_r2 = updater (3, 2, m_c3_r2);
      m_c4_r2 = updater (4, 2, m_c4_r2);
      m_c0_r3 = updater (0, 3, m_c0_r3);
      m_c1_r3 = updater (1, 3, m_c1_r3);
      m_c2_r3 = updater (2, 3, m_c2_r3);
      m_c3_r3 = updater (3, 3, m_c3_r3);
      m_c4_r3 = updater (4, 3, m_c4_r3);
      m_c0_r4 = updater (0, 4, m_c0_r4);
      m_c1_r4 = updater (1, 4, m_c1_r4);
      m_c2_r4 = updater (2, 4, m_c2_r4);
      m_c3_r4 = updater (3, 4, m_c3_r4);
      m_c4_r4 = updater (4, 4, m_c4_r4);
      m_c0_r5 = updater (0, 5, m_c0_r5);
      m_c1_r5 = updater (1, 5, m_c1_r5);
      m_c2_r5 = updater (2, 5, m_c2_r5);
      m_c3_r5 = updater (3, 5, m_c3_r5);
      m_c4_r5 = updater (4, 5, m_c4_r5);
      m_c0_r6 = updater (0, 6, m_c0_r6);
      m_c1_r6 = updater (1, 6, m_c1_r6);
      m_c2_r6 = updater (2, 6, m_c2_r6);
      m_c3_r6 = updater (3, 6, m_c3_r6);
      m_c4_r6 = updater (4, 6, m_c4_r6);
      m_c0_r7 = updater (0, 7, m_c0_r7);
      m_c1_r7 = updater (1, 7, m_c1_r7);
      m_c2_r7 = updater (2, 7, m_c2_r7);
      m_c3_r7 = updater (3, 7, m_c3_r7);
      m_c4_r7 = updater (4, 7, m_c4_r7);
      m_c0_r8 = updater (0, 8, m_c0_r8);
      m_c1_r8 = updater (1, 8, m_c1_r8);
      m_c2_r8 = updater (2, 8, m_c2_r8);
      m_c3_r8 = updater (3, 8, m_c3_r8);
      m_c4_r8 = updater (4, 8, m_c4_r8);
      m_c0_r9 = updater (0, 9, m_c0_r9);
      m_c1_r9 = updater (1, 9, m_c1_r9);
      m_c2_r9 = updater (2, 9, m_c2_r9);
      m_c3_r9 = updater (3, 9, m_c3_r9);
      m_c4_r9 = updater (4, 9, m_c4_r9);
    }

  }
}
```